# asp.net insert text to database works in Chrome/Firefox, but doesnt work in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, internet-explorer

I have a very weird problem, I have an ASP.NET file which takes user's input and insert into database. This screen works with chrome/firefox properly but it doesnt work with IE. I see that , in IE, it insert a row but it inserts EMPTY strings.

here is one of the textbox which is inserted as empty string in IE

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_post_header" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

here is the submit button's code.

```
 protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DbCommand dbCommand;
    try
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("MedBul_New_Post");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "PostHeader", DbType.String, txt_post_header.Text.Trim());
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "PostBody", DbType.String, txt_post_body.Text.Trim());
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);

        Session["TestSessionPostHeader"] = txt_post_header.Text.Trim();
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_result.Text = "Error Submit 1: " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
```

I have never had this problem, I know html+css+javascript can behave differently in different browsers but I have never seen that code behind can behave differently.

what do you think the problem is?

Comment: I see C# and ASP.NET, but no HTML+CSS+JavaScript - so start with troubleshooting. Use IE Developer Tools to see what data is sent from the browsers. Is the "empty" field transmitted from the browser at all?

Comment: I am trying to troubleshout it with IE Developer Tools, but since it is submited, I cannot watch what is submitted. is there any way to do it?

Comment: Good question .. is there a way to Persist the Networking Logging? (I don't use IE often.)

Comment: I dont use IE either :) and it is terrible to troubleshoot in IE. I havent figured it out

Comment: If you can't figure out network logging from inside IE, [Fiddle2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) may be an option.

Comment: how do you see what is posted in that program fiddle2?